# Laravel cannot use object of type Eloquent/Builder as array

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

As i'm now working with **laravel**, i have to display some data on the interface.
But Laravel is installed on the **computer X**, and the database is on a distant **Y server**.
For testing purpose, i am trying to display simple data from a table, the first information of the following table :

Table **site** :
**code_site** varchar(255) primary key

So, this is how i made it :

**database.php**

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => '126.x.x.x',
    'database'  => 'MYNET',
    'username'  => 'mynet',
    'password'  => 'mypassword',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'port'      => '3308',
),
```

**model/Site.php**

```
<?php

class Site extends Eloquent {
<empty because i don't need relations for now> }
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::model('site', 'Site');
Route::get('liste_sites', array('uses' => 'HomeController@liste_sites', 'as' => 'liste_sites'));
```

**liste_sites.blade.php**

```
@for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($sites); $i ++)
    <p>{{$sites[$i]->code_site}}</p>
@endfor
```

**HomeController.php**

```
public function liste_sites() 
    {
        $sites = Site::select('code_site')
        ->orderBy('code_site','desc');

        return View::make('liste_sites', array( 'sites' => $sites, 'which_actif' => 1));
    }
```

But i get the error

```
Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as array
```

Is it because my data are not readable ?

Comment: Your $sites variable holds an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder because you have not called a method on it to retrieve the data the query builder is relating to. As Tim says below, you can call get() on it and you will have the results returned. As you can see with your statement, you call select() then orderBy(). The object returned by select is chain-able to allow you to call subsequent methods in order to build your query. Things like order, limit etc. The get() method call will finally execute the built query.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$sites = Site::select('code_site')->orderBy('code_site','desc');
```

to this:

```
$sites = Site::select('code_site')->orderBy('code_site','desc')->get();
```

I'm pretty sure that should fix it.

Basically, until you call one of the closing functions `->get()`, `->paginate(10)` or `->first()` $sites is treated as a Query, and not an array of `Site` objects, and as such can't be used in a view. Hope that helps!

Comment: It is working
I wasn't aware that paginate execute the request. Thanks !

Comment: No problem! I ran into this issue in a number of my queries until I found this out :P.